# How to Submit Date/Subject data from one List to a Calendar List?

Tags: data, submit

I currently have a custom list created that the team fills out and submits/saves. When this is done, I would like two fields of data from the List form, **Requested Date** and **Subject**, to automatically populate an entry to the team Calendar.

I have read posts that somewhat relate referring to using an "ID" field to make sure that a connection exists that is identifiable.

But how do I setup the proper rule or action on the form submit to make the automatic Calendar entry work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Sharepoint Designer then the easiest thing to do would be to write a simple Workflow that would run on the Original List and then create a new entry in the Calendar.

Comment: Yes we do have SP Designer... So is this something that occurs when submitting the form each time to the List? Or does the work flow simply run on a set schedule? Although we have used SP for a few years now... using these sorts of features is rather new to us and I am slowly learning things... so any further guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: most likely you will want the Workflow to run when the item is initially created in the first list. You set this up when you are in list settings and select Workflow and there you pick the option of when you want it to run.

Comment: What your wanting to do is pretty straight forward and relatively easy to accomplish. if you or somebody on your team has any kind of  programming history or skills, it is fairly straight forward to pick up. First thing is to initiate SP Designer 2013, connect to a site (File-Sites then use copy paste or type in the url). once connected to the site you will want to Create a REUSABLE WORKFLOW. The first thing to do when the workflow screen pops up, is in the Transition stage is to click in it, then on the top ribbon select Add Action. in the Transition Stage click Stage and select End WF

Comment: Thanks for the responses Jeff... Since my last post, I did setup a custom workflow but to kick-off when a specific field in the form is completed after the fact, something that would occur after the form is initially setup/filled out. I have yet to see this "trigger" work. So based on your responses, are you saying that a workflow only works on the initial completion of the form? Can one not kick-off a work flow based on a field being completed?

Comment: You certainly can have a workflow trigger when an Item is modified. And then in the Workflow a Condition Check that If DateField is greater than 1/1/2001 (unfortunately for dates, you can't check for empty or not, so I just use "is greater than" some date in the past) the update list item...

Answer (score 0):

Based on recent input provided, I went into the custom workflow that I had created previously and made some adjustments... and BAMM! it started to work... had a coworker come up to me asking about it... I had not clue it was working... However, it required another tweak which was made and now we are going to keep an eye on it. Appreciate the help provided!!